# seeking for the function latlon2dist in matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

I would like to be able to calculate distance between my coordinates so to be able to use this on my x-axis.

I note that the function 'latlon2dist' seems to give what I want but I do not find it.

Anyone who can help in that regards, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What makes you think this is a matlab function if you can't find it in matlab? Where did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

[latlon2dist](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/synchrony/functions/latlon2dist) as far as I can tell is found in R, although it's possible someone at some point has written a MATLAB function by the same name.

If you have the Mapping toolbox, the function you need is simply called `distance`.  For example to measure the great circle distance between two points:

`arclen = distance('gc',[37,-76],[37,-9])`

Comment: thanks that helps - and yes I actually ended up adapting the latlon2dist from R in matlab.